# Proving the inverse image of a subalgebra under a homomorphism is a subalgebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $h : \mathbf{A} \rightarrow \mathbf{B}$ be a homomorphism of $\Sigma$-algebras. Given any subalgebra $\mathbf{Y}$ of $\mathbf{B}$, prove that $h^{-1}(Y)$ is a subalgebra of $\mathbf{A}$ (denoted by $h^{-1}(\mathbf{Y}))$.

I think I have most of it, but I get stuck in showing that each function in the subalgebra $h^{-1}(\mathbf{Y})$ is a restriction of the corresponding function in $\mathbf{A}$.

Comment: why do you have to show that "each ... in A"?

Comment: It's one of the conditions for a subalgebra given in the textbook that I'm using. Logic for Computer Science: Foundations of Automatic Theorem Proving if you're curious. Is that not typical?

Comment: Well take a function $f$ of arity $n$ and $a_1,...,a_n$ such that $a_1,...,a_n \in h^{-1}(Y)$, and then prove that $f(a_1,...,a_n) \in h^{-1}(Y)$ : what is causing you trouble ?

Comment: Okay, I have shown this which shows that $h^{-1}(Y)$ is closed under its operations. But this does not show that each function is a restriction of the corresponding function in A does it? Does that arise just from the fact that $h^{-1}(Y)$ is a subset of A? I was trying to prove that for any $f_{h^{-1}(Y)}$ of arity $n$, $f_{h^{-1}(Y)}(a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n}) = f_{A}(a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n})$. Is this not needed?